# Powershell script launch Putty

Tags: powershell, putty

I would like to create a powershell script allowing me to launch PuTTy with parameters to connect in serial inform with a "read-host"
Here is my code for now:

```
#For Serial connection
$ConnectionType = Read-Host "Enter your Connection type"
$SerialLine = Read-Host "Enter Your SerialLine like COM1"
$Speed = Read-Host "Enter your Bauds speed"

putty.exe $ConnectionType $SerialLine $Speed
```

And just during the launch of my script I can enter my information but an error window of putty marks me "unexpected argument "9600""

I don't know where I screwed up in my code or if it's just that putty doesn't like working with powershell.
I would really appreciate your help

Thanks a lot !

Comment: what do you expect your users try to enter when prompted for connection type? reading https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.76/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline it seems like you should use "-serial" for $ConnectionType" and "-sercfg 9600,8,n,1,N" for $Speed. Doesn't look very flexible your script, as you won't need baud rate for types other than serial i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell has an SSH module built-in for creating remote connections.
See [PowerShell Docs for SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-7.2#powershell-remoting-example)

As you can see in the [Putty Commandline docs](https://documentation.help/PuTTY/using-cmdline-session.html), Putty requires different parameters to start putty.exe from the command-line.

Comment: Hello, I think I may have solved the problem, indeed I came across this doc and it seems to work with my parameters that I enter like "SerialLine" and bauds.

(I specify that it is a purely educational script aiming to improve myself in scripting) so it is not too serious if it does not work :)